# Sidekiq undefined method for string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

Here is what I'm calling:

```
UpdateRatingAndCountWorker.perform_async(133)
```

Here is my worker:

```
# app/workers/update_rating_and_count_worker.rb
class UpdateRatingAndCountWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(review_id)
    review = Review.find(review_id.to_i)
    review.style.update_average_rating!
  end
end
```

Here is the error:

```
"NoMethodError: undefined method `style' for \"#<Review:0x00000005bef438>\":String"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the error message it looks like the variable `review.style` is of the type `String`.

Since you haven't posted the code for the model `Review` I can only guess but, should it be

```
# app/workers/update_rating_and_count_worker.rb
class UpdateRatingAndCountWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(review_id)
    review = Review.find(review_id.to_i)
    review.update_average_rating!
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I am passing an id and finding a review based on that id. Review belongs to Style. It seems like the review object is a string for some reason and doesn't have the ability to call its association within the worker?

Comment: Hmm ok that sounds weird, if you try to run the code inside `perform` in the console does it work then?

Answer (score 0):

Restart Sidekiq works for me, it picks up new method in my model